# Using plotly how can I fill different color for each group in rows of box-plot

Tags: python, graph, boxplot, plotly-python

I am pretty new to python. I worked on a box plot but found it hard to fill different colors for each group.
I tried to get all to have a black outline but can't get them to be filled the boxplot with designated colors(as in the frame I use to highlight each row in the image attached.

[image]

kindly help

See code and result:

```
df = pd.read_csv (path)

#colors = {'Csi':'#DF9720', 'Ph':'#138245', 'Qc':'#A0D855'}
colors = {'Csi':'#000000', 'Ph':'#000000', 'Qc':'#000000'}

fig = px.box(df, x="RD", y="PRI", facet_col='DARC',facet_row='Species', width= 800, height= 930, color='Species', color_discrete_map = colors)
for data in fig.data:
    data["width"] = 17 #Change this value for bar widths
    data['whiskerwidth'] = 0.5
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=5),fillcolor='#A0D855')

fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor='white',plot_bgcolor= 'white',margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=20, b=20),
    title=None,
    yaxis_range=[-0.2,0.05],
    font=dict(
        family="Arial",
        size=15,
        color='black',
    )
)

fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1.2, linecolor='black', mirror = True, ticks='outside', tickfont_size=16, tickfont_family='Arial', tick0=0, dtick=25)
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1.2, linecolor='black', mirror = True, ticks='outside', tickfont_size=16, tickfont_family='Arial', tick0=-0.20, dtick=0.05)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Hi @Gabriel - Can you pls provide some sufficient sample data so the issue can be recreated? Also, what exactly are you expecting? Do you want the color inside all the boxes on first row to be one color while it is a different color for all boxes in the second row? Please elaborate...

Comment: Thanks, @Redox. I have attached here a sample. Yes, I want the first row to be one color and all in the second row to be another color. While the lines remain black. See the link below for sample data. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1plBbgWB8UtP5dMgVH9NEswkQwJ29yH7C/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @Gabirel - As far as I am aware, you can have different colors for each row, but the box fill color will be a lighter shade of the border color. You can change the fill color to be the same for all rows and keep the border color different, but not the other way around. Let me know if that helps, I will add the answer

Comment: Hi @Redox, thank you for your response. After a careful look at my code, I was able to find a way around it. Thank you. I added a black marker in the data for-loop, then tweaked the "fig.update_traces" line to assign fill colors for each group (row - species as in my data).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new code that gives me the answer to my initial question.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import statistics
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import plotly.io as pio

path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/TK_forGraph.csv'

df = pd.read_csv (path)

fig = px.box(df, x="RD", y="PRI", facet_col='DARC',facet_col_spacing=0.045,facet_row='Species', width= 870, height= 910, color='Species', points='all')

for data in fig.data:
    data["width"] = 17 #Change this value for boxplot widths
    data['whiskerwidth'] = 0.5
    data['line']=dict(width=1,color='#5a5a5a')
    data['pointpos'] = 0 #to display data points in the middle of boxplot
    data['marker']=dict(color='#000000', opacity=0.4, size = 8) #for the data points

#To give specific colors to each group
fig.update_traces(fillcolor='#DF9720', selector=dict(name="Csi"))
fig.update_traces(fillcolor='#138245', selector=dict(name="Ph"))
fig.update_traces(fillcolor='#A0D855', selector=dict(name="Qc"))


fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor='white',plot_bgcolor= 'white',margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=20, b=20),
    title=None,
    yaxis_range=[-0.20,0.05],
    font=dict(
        family="Arial",
        size=15,
        color='black',
    )
)


fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1.2, linecolor='black', mirror = True, ticks='outside', tickfont_size=16, tickfont_family='Arial', tick0=0, dtick=25)
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1.2, linecolor='black', mirror = True, ticks='outside', tickformat='.2f', tickfont_size=16, tickfont_family='Arial', tick0=-0.20, dtick=0.05)


fig.show()
```